Why my LIKE query is so slow with ORDER BY keyword?
I have a simple query running in MariaDB 10.4.12:
SELECT *
FROM transazioni tr
LEFT JOIN acqurienti a ON tr.acquirente=a.id
WHERE
tr.frontend=1
AND tr.stato!=0
AND a.cognome LIKE 'AnyText%'
ORDER BY tr.creazione

This table has these indexes:
frontend int field with cardinality 166
creazione datatime field with cardinality 123541 (all rows of the table)
And this is its Explain:
+-----+--------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id  | select_type  | table  |  type   |             possible_keys               |    key     | key_len  |                ref                 | rows  |    Extra    |
+-----+--------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1  | SIMPLE       | tr     | index   | acquirente,frontend                     | creazione  |       6  | NULL                               |  793  | Using where |
|  1  | SIMPLE       | a      | eq_ref  | PRIMARY                                 | PRIMARY    |       4  | tr.acquirente                      |    1  | Using where |
+-----+--------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+

For some reason it takes about 12s because it uses creazione index that is a datetime.
If I remove ORDER BY creazione it speed up to 0.4s and its explain changes to:
+-----+--------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+
| id  | select_type  | table  |  type   |             possible_keys               |        key          | key_len  |      ref       | rows  |    Extra    |
+-----+--------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+
|  1  | SIMPLE       | tr     | ref     | acquirente,frontend                     | frontend            |       5  | const          | 3112  | Using where |
|  1  | SIMPLE       | a      | eq_ref  | PRIMARY                                 | PRIMARY             |       4  | tr.acquirente  |    1  | Using where |
+-----+--------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+

I cannot understand why the key changes due to ORDER BY keyword switching to a worse cardinality. As far as I know the ORDER is applied after the where, and here for this example the where filters limits the resultset to only 2 rows.
I know a solution can be change the frontend index to (frontend,creazione) and remove the single creazione index, but I'm missing the logic of key selection. And moreover, I may need the single creazione index for some other queries.
Why the order by deceives the index selection?

If you create a covering index, the query should be performant.

what about select * from (select * from ... where ...) order by creazione?

It is an idea, but why the default selection doesn't work and give precedence to order by instead of where fields?

please include output of show create table yourtablename for the tables in your query with all performance questions

basically the optimizer has to guess whether reading using the index that provides rows already in the desired order is faster than using an index that filters the rows but then has to sort them afterwards.  just do from transazioni tr use index (frontend)

Take a look at optimizer trace for how queries are planned and analyze format=json for how they are executed. Also because you have a AND a. LIKE absolute critiera, it could be a [inner] JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN as a.x LIKE ... will never match a NULL version of a.x.

It looks like that LEFT JOIN is really a JOIN.  Given that, the Optimizer can start with either table.
These should help either case:
tr:  INDEX(frontend, creazione)
tr:  INDEX(frontend, acquirente)
a:  INDEX(cognome)

